# how to import a (txt) into json object

Tags: php, json, import

So I have created php file that receives pulse data from an Arduino Pulse sensor an stores it into .txt file. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$pulse = $_GET["pulse"] ;   

$file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");

$pulse.="\r\n";
fwrite($file, $pulse);//takes incoming data and writes it in the file
fclose($file);?>
```

So What I am storing in my data.txt are just a bunch of numbers from a pulse sensor. I want to have access to that data.txt from a different php file as a json object, so I came up with this but it does not seem to work:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

if(isset($_GET["request"])){

    if($_GET["request"] == "info"){

        $pulse = $_GET["pulse"];

        $file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");


        $pulse.="\r\n";
        fwrite($file, $pulse);
        fclose($file);


        echo json_encode($file);



    }
}

?>
```

Any suggestion is more than welcome, I kind of have a feeling that it is possible.

Best,

M

Comment: What are the actual contents of the file (besides a bunch of newlines)?

Comment: They are just a bunch of numbers. We are still figuring it out if they come all as a stringer or single integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I can come up with at simplest..

```
<?php

        header('Content-type: application/json');

         // make your required checks

        $fp    = 'yourfile.txt';

        // get the contents of file in array
        $conents_arr   = file($fp,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

        foreach($conents_arr as $key=>$value)
        {
            $conents_arr[$key]  = rtrim($value, "\r");
        }

        var_dump($conents_arr);
        $json_contents = json_encode($conents_arr);

        echo $json_contents;
?>
```

This will first convert your file contents into array and then make json out of it ..expected output will be something like ["data1","data2","data3"]

Hope it helps you

Comment: This definitely worked. I'm going to try the other two suggestions. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you want...

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode( explode("\r\n",file_get_contents('data.txt')) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the actual content of your data file, you just have to read the data of your file, store this data into an array and then echo the array using `json_encode`

```
<?php

// Send header for json content
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

// Check if the user asking info
    if(!empty($_GET["request"]) && $_GET["request"] == "info") {

```
    // Retrieve the content of the file and split on "\r\n"
    // ($data is an array of lines)
    $data = preg_split("/\r\n/", file_get_contents("data.txt"));

    // JSON encode the data array
    echo json_encode($file);

}
```

Assuming pulse data are simple integer for example, you will send a JSON like:

```
["12","24","20",....]
```